# Search for -1 in Solr

Tags: search, solr

I have an optional property of type pfloat, that can either be an encoded numeric value, or -1 if the property is not set. Numerics are encoded to be range searchable (1 is encoded to something like 10000000001), but -1 will always be  -1.

How can I search a field for -1?

`property:-1` throws parse error and `property:'-1'` doesn't return anything.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use double quotes: `property:"-1"`

Answer (score 0):

Try:
`*:* NOT property:[0 TO *]`